# How to combine multiple maps in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is there a Hive UDF that creates a map with unique values?
For ex:

```
col_1 | col_2
-------------
a      |   x
a      |   y
b      |   y
b      |   y
c      |   z
c      |   NULL
d      |   NULL
```

This should return a map as follows

```
{ a : [x,y], b : [y], c:[z] }
```

I'm looking for something similar to presto's `multimap_aggfunction`

Comment: do you need the output as one row?

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect_set` to remove duplicate col_2 per col_1 and then use `map` on this output.

```
select map(col_1,uniq_col_2)
from (select col_1,collect_set(col_2) as uniq_col2
      from tbl
      where col_2 is not null
      group by col_1
     ) t
```